# Search Instagram by user and tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

Does anyone know is this is possible?  I have a script that uses the Instagram RSS feed to search for specific hashtags.  I then filter those images for a specific user based on the `credit.content` item.  It all works fine except for one thing - Instagram only provides access to 20 images and if the specific user's images are not in the most recent 20 images for the selected tag, then there is a null result.  The only option seems to be to set up a script to search by user first - and then to parse the results to match the specific tag.  Unfortunately there is no user search RSS equivalent to the tag search RSS, so it's back to the API.  How can I set up a search (where I can vary the user at any time) and then search the results for the specific tag?  I should add, I don't want to do this just for me - I want to be able to set it up so that users of my site can simply enter their own Instagram user ID and selected hashtag and then have their own images displayed.  (I know there are other online services offering a similar service, but I need this to happen on my site.)

I don't have access to any server scripts so would prefer to do it all client side in javascript/jquery if possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: See the Instagram API: http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Yeah, fair point.  :)  Sorry, I didn't make myself clear...I was hoping there was a smart way to do this without having to get an access token for each user - something similar to the RSS tag feed.